# PHP filesize for absolute path

Tags: php, filesize

I was surprised PHP's [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) fails on absolute paths??
My files are on my own server, how can I get the filesize except from converting them to relative (a mess)

**EDIT**

example:

```
$filename = 'http://172.16.xx.x/app/albums/002140/tn/020.jpg';
echo $filename . ': ' . filesize($filename) . ' bytes';

Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for http://172.16.xx.x/app/albums/002140/tn/020.jpg in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/app/admin/+tests/filesize.php on line 26
```

**END EDIT**

I found this example for remote files:

```
$filename = 'http://www.google.com/logos/2010/stevenson10-hp.jpg';
$headers = get_headers($filename, 1);
echo $headers['Content-Length']; // size in bytes
```

Does this work without downloading the files?

Comment: It would work if you gave it a filesystem URL, rather than an HTTP URL.  How is PHP supposed to know how to resolve the above URL to your local filesystem?

Comment: I've never heard of there being a problem with using absolute paths, and I've never encountered that, either. Which OS are you using, and can you give an example of the code that is not working?

Comment: mmm, now that I think of it yes, I understand. Poor PHP..

Comment: @Alex I am on OSX with XAMPP, it does not work here. I'll try it online.

Answer (score 5):

`http://172.16.xx.x/app/albums/002140/tn/020.jpg` is not an absolute path, it is an URL. The absolute path for it would be something like `/var/www/app/albums/002140/tn/020.jpg`. You should use that absolute path in `filesize()`.

`filesize()` supports only URL wrappers that support `stat()`. HTTP and HTTPS doesn't support that as mentioned in the manual page for [HTTP and HTTPS wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php).

Answer (score 2):

Yes It will be work fine .

```
$filename = 'http://172.16.xx.x/app/albums/002140/tn/020.jpg';

$headers  = get_headers($filename, 1);

$fsize    = $headers['Content-Length'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this ... for get file size by URL

```
$ch = curl_init('http://172.16.xx.x/app/albums/002140/tn/020.jpg');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

 curl_close($ch);
 echo $size;
```

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, you're trying to give an HTTP URL to `filesize()`, which will not work.  `filesize()` works on local filesystem URLs, such as those listed at http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php.

Presumably, as you're trying to access files on your own server, you must have the filesystem URL, rather than just an HTTP URL?

Comment: @FFish: It does work with absolute paths, but they must be filesystem paths.

Answer (score 1):

**To use Function filesize();**

**you should have absolute path not the urls**

http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.filesize.php

Answer (score 0):

get_headers() will send a GET to your server, this add load to your web server.

I don't get it, your filesize() fails on absolute path ? It should not. According to php.net :
http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php

**Edit:**
I'm not sure about the error PHP will give you if allow_url_fopen is set to 0, but check this line in your PHP.ini (and restart apache then) : http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

If it's off, filesize() will not handle URL. Let me know if it was that.

Answer (score -3):

I think you would have to use the `filesize()` function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

```
echo filesize( $filename );
```

Comment: @FFish: You will need to give a concrete example of some code that doens't work.